# A program that Continuously track a process running on a remote machine from another machine.

Tags: java

I have an idea that I am trying to implement with Java, but I am a little confuse on the best approach and  process I should take, so hopefully can point me on the right direction and I can further investigate.

Basically I am trying to do this:

I would like to create a program that Continuously track a process running on a remote machine from another machine.  These machines could be Unix-Unix, Unix-Windows or Windows-Windows.

For example:

Lets say I have a process xxxx with  PID 154 running  in machine A.  I want to be able to connect from machine B, and continuously check that this process is still running.  If this process is not longer running, I will make a file I have in machine B to change its name.  It should continuously check for this process, because if the process is back on, it should rename the file back to the way it was.  It will check for the process name, not the PID since that could change.

So far, I did a program that test a local process running and rename the file if it is not running.

I believe I can  use socket to connect to the other server, but normally socket is for 
implementing network services -- such as remote login (rlogin, telnet) and file transfer (FTP) -- which require data of indefinite length to be transferred, but not for continuous check if a process is running.  So I guess I can use Socket to connect, but I need something else to check if the processes continuously running.  If not I should send a message to take the next action.

Any ideas or place where I can further read are more than welcome.

Thanks

Comment: your code can try to ssh to the remote server then run commands in remote machine.. (NB: sry I haven't read your full post.)

Comment: Are you sure that you want to build it from scratch? You could use something like [this](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) or [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/process-monitor)

Comment: Yes I prefer to start from scratch, I am trying  to  practice Java, and this is a good way to keep myself busy using it.  I started looking into using jsch...so I'll let you know how it goes.  Thanks

Comment: Somehow I keep getting this error message after I compile:C:\Support\Tools\Java>javac -classpath jsch/jsch-0.1.42.jar  LicenseCheck.java

C:\Support\Tools\Java>
C:\Support\Tools\Java>java -classpath jsch/jsch-0.1.42.jar LicenseCheck
Error: Could not find or load main class LicenseCheck ....It can't load the main class for some reason.  What am I  missing?  Please advice.  Thanks.

Comment: I managed to get pass the error message by doing this:javac -d . -classpath pathtojar\jsch\jsch-0.1.42.jar javaprogram.java

java packagename.javaprogram
In case this may  help somebody else.

Comment: Hi

So far, I am able to connect and determine if the process with name "lmgrd" is running, but I am still having the following problem:

a)It only check once if "lmgrd" is present or not.  I like to make it a continuous check for that process, and if at some point it notices it is not longer running.  Then the else condition will get into action.

If anyone can give me some hints on this, I would really appreciate.
Thanks.  Below is the code I have so far....

Comment: while((msg=in.readLine())!=null){
                     System.out.println(msg);
                 if(msg.contains("lmgrd")){
                        System.out.println("lmgrd is running...System on the watch...");
                      
                    }else{
                        .........
                    }